# How to set a default page to display in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I just finish my app and deployed it to Firebase, however I'm getting `error 404` that it cant find the home file, so I'll have to manually add `/home.html` at the back of the URL (`https://website.web.app/home.html`) before it display my app on the browser. Any idea on how to set a default page in the `.json` file Please. I used Bootstrap, html for the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.html is the default page for Firebase Hosting.  According to the [configuration documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config), there doesn't appear to be a way to change this.  It's probably going to be easiest for you to simply use index.html instead of home.html.

You could also attempt to use a [rewrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) to change requests to home.html into a request for index.html, but I think it will be easier to just change the name of your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirects option from "firebase.json" config:

```
    {
        "hosting": {
            ...
            "redirects": [
                {
                    "source": "/index.html",
                    "destination": "/home.html",
                    "type": 301
                },
                {
                    "source": "/",
                    "destination": "/home.html",
                    "type": 301
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```